# My website text is not rendering on iOS devices

Tags: html, css, ios, text

When i run the website on Android or Windows the text renders normally and everything works super smooth but when I run the website on iOS the text is just gone. Like it never existed. All other elements tuck in. It is almost as if all text has display: none;

[not working on iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdiLL.jpg)

[working on Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2w3X1.jpg)

Here is my html:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link id="normalStylesheet" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Tungstun Design and ICT</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="main_section">
        <div class="header"
        data-aos="header-scroll"
        data-aos-offset="100"
        data-aos-duration="300"
        data-aos-once="false"
        data-aos-anchorPlacement="top-bottom"
        data-aos-anchor=".work_content"
        data-aos-easing="ease-in-out">
            <ul id="header">
                <li id="homeButton" class="headerItem"><a>Home</a></li>
                <li id="workButton" class="headerItem"><a>Work</a></li>
                <li id="contactButton" class="headerItem"><a>Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <img class="header_logo" src="images/logo@2x.png">
        </div>
        
        <div id="homeSection" class="logo_container">
            <img class="logo" src="images/logo@2x.png"> 
        </div>
    
        <div class="buttons_container">
            <button id="workMainButton" class="button primary_button">Work</button>
            <button id="contactMainButton" class="button secondary_button">Contact</button>
        </div>
        
        <div class="image_div">
            <img src="images/bgovals@2x.png" id="bgOvals">
        </div>
        <div class="circle_div"
        data-aos="tagline-scroll"
        data-aos-offset="100"
        data-aos-duration="300"
        data-aos-once="false"
        data-aos-anchorPlacement="top-bottom"
        data-aos-anchor=".work_content"
        data-aos-easing="ease-in-out">
            <img src="images/bgcircle@2x.png" id="bgCircle">
            <h1 id="tagLine">A small IT and design company based in Utrecht</h1>
        </div>
        
        <div class="bottom_stroke"><hr><hr><hr></div>
    </div>
    <div id="workSection" class="work_content">
        <h1 class="title">My work</h1>
        <ul id="workList" class="work_list">

            <li>
                <div class="work_li_div">
                    <img src="images/amblogo.png" class="work_image">
                    <div class="work_name_div">Alles met boeken</div>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li>
                <div class="work_li_div">
                    <img src="images/Herfst.png" class="work_image">
                    <div class="work_name_div">VanGister</div>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li>
                <div class="work_li_div">
                    <img src="images/logo-transparent@2x.png" class="work_image">
                    <div class="work_name_div">Heimstel</div>
                </div>
            </li>

            
        </ul>
        <div class="bottom_stroke"><hr><hr><hr></div>
    </div>

    

    <div id="contactSection" class="contact_content">
        <h1 class="title">Contact me</h1>
        <h2>Let's make something great together!</h2>
        <div class="form_div">
            <form>
                <label for="formName">Your name</label><br>
                <input id="formName" type="text"><br>
                <label for="formEmail">Your e-mail</label><br>
                <input id="formEmail" type="email"><br>
                <label for="formType">What can I do for you?</label><br>
                <select id="formType"></select><br>
                <form action="formMessage">Anything to add?</form>
                <textarea id="formMessage" type="text"></textarea><br>
                <button id="formConfirmButton" type="button">Shoot!</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="bottom_stroke"><hr><hr><hr></div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="work.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
        AOS.init();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here my css

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: gotham_medium;
    src: url(font/GothamMedium.svg);
    src: url(font/GothamMedium.ttf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: gotham_book;
    src: url(font/GothamBook.svg);
    src: url(font/GothamBook.ttf);
}

html, body {
    background-color: var(--tungstun-background);
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: 'gotham_medium', 'Open Sans', sans-serif;;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

Comment: you are missing fonts formats needed for ios like `woff`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27158639/font-face-not-working-on-ios

Comment: Thanks for helping! I added the .woff and .woff2 file formats and now iOS displays it perfectly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation is correct, but the .ttf file is corrupted. Chrome is more forgiving than safari, but you can see that the font behaves weird on chrome, too (compare the two pictures using your font and the browser default font)

[image: With your font]

[image: With Times New Roman]

Load the font from a trusted source and if you refactored that font using an online service, try another one. The website itself works, you can test it by changing the font.